# GCM server crashes on online domain

Tags: android, jsp, servlets, google-cloud-messaging, java-server

Hey I have been following gcm tutorial to create gcm-demo-server and a demo-client.
All was working well on tomcat,

I then uploaded the .war file on a free jsp domain

firstly the page said "No devices registered "
as soon as I got registered from my android it appeared that 1 device is registered

I pressed the send button to send notification on the device and the server crashed with the following errors

```
    ype Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission android.googleapis.com:443 connect,resolve)
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:271)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:328)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:793)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:896)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:479)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:458)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
    com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:94)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 logs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some Authentication problem may be due to Key your using. I don't know the exact problem in it. Refer this tutorial it may help you,

http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/

it works fine for me.

Comment: yeah I followed this tutorial too and my server is working fine on tomcat
The problem occurs when I try to send message from online server/ from online domain

Comment: Give some log(sysout) in server side and check what response it sends to mobile device. And see the log in mobile too we can find where is the problem

Comment: no need for that the problem is with permissions.. I have dig through google .. solution for such a problem is I need to have server.policy and client.policy files which will define permissions but I can't figure out where to locate them